# VBA selecting tab on webpage which refers to Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

I've got the following HTML code (see below) where I want to click on the button on this webpage called NBT Order Intake. I got my code working for everything except clicking on this tab header (no URL behind tab so cannot navigate that way). I believe the useful code is between the two highlighted section in the image.

I've tried query selector . click with name and ID as well as the get element function.

Any help would be appreciated (only need the 1 line of code to add to my string)

nb. website is secure and has log in so cannot share URL hence image of code.

---

**HTML:**

```html
name="home_tab_name_97" value="KPI - Best Card Jobs"/></div>
<div id="home_tab_98" class="home_tab" title="" >
   <div class="home_tab_inner"><span id="home_tab_label_98" onclick="SelectHomeTab(98)">NBT Order Intake</span>&nbsp;<img src="Includes.aspx?type=image&amp;name=Images/lsd_down.gif" border="0" class="home_tab_setting" onclick="HomeTabSettings(98)" /></div>
   <div class="el_hidden" id="home_tab_settings_98">
      <div><a class="mnu_item" href="javascript: RenameHomeTab(98)">Rename</a></div>
      <div><a class="mnu_item" href="javascript: DeleteHomeTab(98)">Delete</a></div>
      <div><a class="mnu_item" href="javascript: ShareHomeTab(98)">Make Public</a></div>
      <div><a class="mnu_item" href="javascript: ShowAddDashCustomPageOptions(98)">Add Custom Item</a></div>
      <div class="mnu_item_divider"></div>
      <div><a class="mnu_item" onclick="HideHomeSettings(98)">Cancel</a></div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="home_tab_name_98" name="home_tab_name_98" value="NBT Order Intake"/>
</div>
<div id="home_tab_99" class="home_tab" title="" >
<div class="home_tab_inner">
<span id="home_tab_label_99"
```

---

**Image of HTML:**

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    'add worksheet
    Sheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet

    'destination
    Set destsheet = ActiveSheet

    'use internet explorer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ' with internet open, make this visable and go to webpage x, enter username a
    nd passwork
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("URL")
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'ie.Document.getElementsbyname("User name").Focus
        IE.document.getElementsByName("username")(0).Value = "Username"
        IE.document.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "Pword"
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'look for the input field (HTML CODE)
        Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        i = 0
        While i < objCollection.Length
            If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
               objCollection(i).Name = "" Then
                ' "Search" button is found
                Set objElement = objCollection(i)

            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        '(click the log on)
        objElement.Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With
    With IE
        IE.document.querySelector("input[id=home_tab_name_98]").Click
    End With
    'close the internet page
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah ok found how to enter the code, is there a way to make it more easily visible for youself? Currently its just 1 massive line, do i just need to press enter randomly?

Comment: I have edited so you have a better idea how could look. You can revert all the changes using the rollback feature via [edit] if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#home_tab_label_98").Click
ie.document.querySelector("#home_tab_label_98").FireEvent "onclick"
```

Or

```
ie.document.parentwindow.execscript "SelectHomeTab(98)"
```

---

The actual selection of the element is by CSS selector whereby `#home_tab_label_98` targets the element with id `home_tab_label_98`. The `"#"` is for id.

[image: CSS selector]

---

**If you get object not found then:**

1. Make sure you have a pause before trying to select or attempt to select in a loop;
2. Check for any preceeding form/frame/iframe tags this is nested in. These would need to be navigated to acccess the element;
3. Remember you need  `While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend` after any clicking event or form submit.

**Still not working:**

Please show more html.

Comment: I get run time error '424' no object specified? there are no preceding from tags that I can see but the code is masssive goes on for ever :'( i have to ctrl - f the relevant field.

Comment: check carefully for form/iframe/frame tags. You can ctrl + f search. Also are you leaving enough time for elements to be visible?

Comment: think my code is fine (i've pasted in the question at the bottom ) i believe the wend busy bit should be good enough for page to load but could need a wait of 2 secs of something to be sure.- also still cant see any iforms etc though i could be looking for the wrong stuff, im not that experienced with HTML is there a particular tag i should look for i just ctril+f'ed frame etc found a couple of tags but point to different code which shouldn't be relevant to this tab

Comment: when i try adding application.wait #12:00:02# excel crashes -_- won't work

Comment: Um, this almost works, im a bit puzzled too when VBA opens the webpage this clicks the correct tab but then reverts back to the home tab thne i get a message saying "error occured! unable to get property 'childnodes' of undefined or null reference"  (this is including the delay, written correctly this time!) - also sorry for slow replies just keep getting called into meeting -_-

Comment: It may be that some other form of validation needs to take place.

Comment: the only bits of HTML the relates to the button (tab) i want to click I have sent you :( and I have very little knowledge of this kind of database so i got no idea how to make this work -_- appreciate the help but think i'll have to accept defeat on this bit of automation, though thanks for the help! just have to manual do the last couple of values.